# Accessing column names of a pandas dataframe within a custom transformer in a Sklearn pipeline with ColumnTransformer?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, pipeline

I need to use a custom transformer within a pipeline that acts using the column names. However, the previous pipeline transformations convert the dataframe to a numpy array. I know I can retrieve the column names from the Column Transformer object *after* the pipeline has been fit, but I need to access the column names *within* the fit step. The custom transformer in my example below is a simple minimal example for illustration only, not the true transformation.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class MyCustomTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def my_custom_transformation(self, X):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        X: pandas dataframe
        """
        columns_to_keep = [col for col in X.columns if col.endswith(('_a', '_b'))]
        return columns_to_keep
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.columns_to_keep = self.my_custom_transformation(X)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X[self.columns]

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('minmax_scaler', MinMaxScaler())])
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('onehot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))])

column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('numeric_transformer', numeric_transformer, ['num']),
    ('categorical_transformer', categorical_transformer, ['cat']),
])

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('column_transformer', column_transformer),
    ('my_custom_transformer', MyCustomTransformer())
])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'num': [1,2,3], 'cat':['a', 'b', 'c']})
pipeline.fit(data_df)
```

which would ideally result as:

```
transformed_df = pipeline.transform(df)
print(transformed_df)
>>>    num    cat_a    cat_b
    0    0        1        0
    1  0.5        0        1
    2    1        0        0
```

The transformations in the column_transformer convert the dataframe to a numpy array, which is then passed to the custom transformer. Obviously this results in an error since you can't get the column names from a numpy array.

I can't use indexing to access the columns since the one-hot encoding can result in an not-previously-known number of columns.

If I could access the ColumnTransformer object within the fit method of the custom transformer, I could retrieve the column names, then create a pandas dataframe to use in the fit method as above (?), but I have not successfully found a way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See my proposed implementation of a `ColumnTransformerWithNames` in response to [how do i get_feature_names using a column transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079602/how-do-i-get-feature-names-using-a-column-transformer).
You can replace the calls to `ColumnTransformer` with `ColumnTransformerWithNames` and the output of the pipeline will be a DataFrame with column names =)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install sklearn-pandas-transformers
```

from sklearn_pandas_transformers.transformers import SklearnPandasWrapper

```
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('numeric_transformer', SklearnPandasWrapper(numeric_transformer), ['num']),
    ('categorical_transformer', SklearnPandasWrapper(categorical_transformer), ['cat']),
])
```